# Unmanaged package error

Tags: code-coverage, unmanaged-package

I have created a lightning component and want to create a package for that i wrote a test class for apex class coverage too which is showing 100% code coverage but when iam trying to upload the aura component iam getting the following error.

> No test methods found in the Apex code included in the package. At least 75% test coverage is required.

Can some one help here.

Comment: Did you include your test class in the package?

Comment: My test class is not visible in apex classes is their any way where it can be found in while creating package

Comment: Even my apex class which i created using developer console is not visible in package manager apex class section iam using sandbox.

Comment: You cannot create managed packages in Sandboxes. Use a developer org for that or go with unlocked packages.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add the `@isTest` annotation to both the main class definition and each test method:

```
@isTest
private class MyTestClass {

    @isTest static void MyTestMethod1() {
        // Unit tests here...
    }

    @isTest static void MyTestMethod2() {}

}
```